# Adding to yaml list using a loop

Tags: loops, variables, yaml, jinja2, ansible

I am using the geerlingguy.firewall ansible galaxy role to add iptables rules. In that there is a firewall_additional_rules list variable where I am adding in some scripts to allow from certain ips, which I want to provide with a another list variable

```
white_listed_ips:
   - 1.1.1.1
   - 1.1.1.2
```

etc

I want to be able to generate the firewall_additional_rules list from the white_listed_ips list, by looping through. However I can't find any way of doing this. Can you loop through variables and add to an array in yaml?

So I want to do something like this in a var file (I know this doesn't work, indulge me)

```
firewall_additional_rules:
{% for ip in white_listed_ips %}
  - iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s {{ ip }} --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
  - iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s {{ ip }} --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
{% endfor %}
```

This is to go into the jinja2 template in the role, you can see here:
https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-firewall/blob/master/templates/firewall.bash.j2

Comment: Can you elaborate on "this doesn't work"? Error message.. Looking at the example (https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/lamp_simple/roles/web/templates/index.php.j2) your code should've worked.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar in the var file, not the jinja template

Answer (score 3):

Ansible playbooks, vars files, etc. are not jinja2 templates, so as you said jinja2 constructs like `{% for ... %}` won't work in them.  But having said that, it would be a simple matter of simply moving the jinja2 code into the template where it should belong anyway.

If you look at `firewall_additional_rules` in [firewall.bash.j2](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-firewall/blob/master/templates/firewall.bash.j2) it's only referenced here:

```
# Additional custom rules.
{% for rule in firewall_additional_rules %}
{{ rule }}
{% endfor %}
```

All you need to do is either change this around or add another for loop before or after it that contains the exact code you already wrote:

```
{% for ip in white_listed_ips %}
  - iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s {{ ip }} --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
  - iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s {{ ip }} --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yep. The only way to translate the ips into rules outside of the normal jinja context will involve `map` and regex. Much easier to do this in the template. Lists -> lists is just ugly with Ansible at the moment.

Comment: Its okay to edit roles that you downloaded off ansible-galaxy. It is not like jquery or some such library which should not be hacked. I think OP is trying to add custom rules without editing the downloaded role

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking, I don't want to edit a role as that means it won't be usable elsewhere. I'm asking for more dynamic ways to alter variables in yaml...is there no way to add to an array/list/whatever? I put the jinja2 syntax in there as an example of what I am trying to do in a var file.

If I can't do this, is there a way of overriding the jinja2 template locally in my project?

Comment: I have exactly the same challenge as @MichaelMallett.